# Make div stay in position after hover

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to make the div tag stay in position after hovering the image.  As of now, the div moves to the right when I hover the image.  I tried using fixed position and absolute, but no luck.  Here is the HTML code:

```
<div>
<button class="buttonTest"></button>
</div>
```

In CSS:

```
.buttonTest{
    background-image:  url('http://hd-wall-papers.com/images/wallpapers/random-       image/random-image-16.jpg');
    width:150px;
    height:150px;

}

div {
  border-style: solid;
  height:auto;
  width:150px;
}

div{
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

div:hover{
  border-width:75px;
  transform: scale(.5);
}
```

In codepen: https://codepen.io/dxs6040/pen/gmPgzz/

Comment: It's kind of unclear what your end goal is. Is this what you're trying to do? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/vxLZRW

Comment: Yes! Plus, I want the border width to thicken as to make it look like the mouse push the button down.

Comment: Updated the pen https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/vxLZRW

Comment: Do you want like this .. https://codepen.io/vaibhaviiit/pen/PpZjvy?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Use box-sizing:border-box and a few changes. Is this the desired behaviour?

```css
.buttonTest{
background-image:  url('http://hd-wall-papers.com/images/wallpapers/random-image/random-image-16.jpg');
  width:100%;
  height:100%;

}


div {
  border-style: solid;
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div:hover{
  border-width:15px;
  transform: scale(.80);
}
```

```html
<div>
<button class="buttonTest"></button>
</div>
<div>
<button class="buttonTest"></button>
</div>
```